# I want the user to type "4", and then have the prograrm repeat code I had earlier in the program

Tags: c#

This is a code snippet from my console program:

```
Console.WriteLine("1.) Tom");
Console.WriteLine("2.) Lucas");
Console.WriteLine("3.) Sarah");
Console.WriteLine("4.) Back");
var userChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
switch (userChoice){
    case "4":

    break;
 }
```

So I'm just trying to find a way I could repeat a line of code earlier in the program. If you have any ideas please share. The line of code I am trying to repeat is similar to this just with the choices: students, honor roll, exit.

Comment: You have to work out the design first. You can divide each part into methods and call the method depending on the input :).

Answer (score 0):

This the function for the choices

```
public void function1 ()

{

    Console.WriteLine("1.) Tom");
    Console.WriteLine("2.) Lucas");
    Console.WriteLine("3.) Sarah");
    Console.WriteLine("4.) Back");

}
```

then you can call it by using this

```
var userChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

switch (userChoice)
{

    case "4":

    function1;

    break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var userChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
switch (userChoice){
    case "4":
        Console.WriteLine("4.) Back");
    break;
 }
```